# Observed Fisher information for the binomial: How is $I(\hat{\theta}) = \frac{n}{\hat{\theta}(1 - \hat{\theta})}$ calculated?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, binomial-distribution, likelihood, fisher-information

I am currently studying the textbook *In All Likelihood* by Yudi Pawitan. **Example 2.10** of chapter **2.5 Maximum and curvature of likelihood** says the following:

> **Example 2.10:** Based on $x$ from the binomial$(n, \theta)$ the log-likelihood function is
> $$\log L(\theta) = x \log \theta + (n - x) \log(1 - \theta).$$
> We can first find the score function
> $$\begin{align} S(\theta) &\equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial{\theta}} \log L(\theta) \\ &= \frac{x}{\theta} - \frac{n - x}{1 - \theta}, \end{align}$$
> giving the MLE $\hat{\theta} = x/n$ and
> $$\begin{align} I(\theta) &\equiv -\frac{\partial^2}{\partial{\theta}^2} \log L(\theta) \\ &= \frac{x}{\theta^2} + \frac{n - x}{(1 - \theta)^2}, \end{align}$$
> so at the MLE we have the Fisher information
> $$I(\hat{\theta}) = \frac{n}{\hat{\theta}(1 - \hat{\theta})}. \square$$

How is $I(\hat{\theta}) = \frac{n}{\hat{\theta}(1 - \hat{\theta})}$ calculated? I know that the MLE $\hat{\theta}$ is the solution of the score equation $S(\theta) \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial{\theta}} \log L(\theta) = 0$, and I know that $I(\theta) \equiv - \frac{\partial^2}{\partial{\theta}^2} \log L(\theta)$ is the Fisher information, but I can't figure out precisely what $I(\hat{\theta})$ is, or exactly how $I(\hat{\theta}) = \frac{n}{\hat{\theta}(1 - \hat{\theta})}$ was calculated.

Comment: Small hint: $I(\theta)=n\left\{\frac{x/n}{\theta^2}+\frac{(n-x)/n}{(1-\theta)^2}\right\}$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396982/fisher-information-of-a-binomial-distribution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Substitute the value $\hat\theta=x/n$ in $I(\theta) .$ See what happens.

Substitute in place of $\theta$ to get $$\frac{n^2x}{x^2}+ \frac{n^2(n-x) }{(n-x) ^2}.$$ Simplify it.

Comment: Thanks, I think I just fixed it. With regards to your hint, there is no $\hat{\theta}$ in $I(\theta)$, so are you saying to substitute $x = \hat{\theta}n$? But, if we do that, then we don't have any way to eliminate the $\theta$ in $I(\theta)$. So, as you can see, I'm confused as to what we're supposed to do here.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the expectation operator in the [definition of Fisher information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information#Definition): $I(\theta) = E_\theta\left[-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\log L(\theta)\right]$ instead of what you posted.  After correcting this and noting $E_\theta(x) = n\theta$ given $x \sim B(n, \theta)$, it turns out that
\begin{align}
 & I(\theta) = E_\theta\left[-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\log L(\theta)\right] \\
=& \frac{1}{\theta^2}E_\theta(x) + \frac{1}{(1 - \theta)^2}E_\theta(n - x) \\
=& \frac{n}{\theta} + \frac{n}{1 - \theta} \\
=& \frac{n}{\theta(1 - \theta)},
\end{align}
matching the goal.

---

Through the discussion below, it seems that the reference you quoted fails to clearly present the concept of "Fisher information" (and other related sample-level concepts).  I will try to clarify them based on Section 4.3 of *Statistical Models* by A. C. Davison.

Suppose $N$ i.i.d. observations $x_1, \ldots, x_N$ are drawn from the  distribution $f(x; \theta)$, so that the log-likelihood is
\begin{align}
\ell(\theta) = \log L(\theta) = \sum_{i = 1}^N \log f(x_i; \theta). 
\end{align}

*Fisher information* (or *expected information*) is defined by
\begin{align}
I(\theta) = E\left[-\frac{\partial^2\ell(\theta)}{\partial\theta^2}\right]. \tag{1}
\end{align}

While the *observed information* is defined as:
\begin{align}
J(\theta) = -\frac{\partial^2\ell(\theta)}{\partial\theta^2}
= -\sum_{i = 1}^N \frac{\partial^2 \log f(x_i; \theta)}{\partial\theta^2}. \tag{2}
\end{align}

Note that, if observations are i.i.d., Fisher information only contains parameter $\theta$ (i.e., no observations are included, but the sample size $N$ is still included).

For your example, you have a single observation $x \sim B(n, \theta)$. In this case, your post and my calculation above showed:
\begin{align}
& I(\theta) = \frac{n}{\theta(1 - \theta)}. \tag{3} \\
& J(\theta) = \frac{x}{\theta^2} + \frac{n - x}{(1 - \theta)^2}. \tag{4}
\end{align}

To evaluate "Fisher information evaluated at MLE $\hat{\theta}$", simply plug in $\hat{\theta}$ into $(3)$ (just like evaluating a function's value at a given point) to get $I(\hat{\theta}) = \frac{n}{\hat{\theta}(1 - \hat{\theta})}$.  Even though $J(\hat{\theta}) = I(\hat{\theta})$ in this case, that doesn't mean $J(\hat{\theta})$ is conceptually "Fisher information evaluated at MLE $\hat{\theta}$".

Comment: This is the way I would generally do and learnt. But the book defined observed $I(\theta) $ without the expectation. I need to digest that.

Comment: Yes, the author doesn't seem to use expectation in the textbook.

Comment: @User1865345 The population-level Fisher information is always defined like that.  The version without "$E$" is usually known as "observed Fisher information".

Comment: @Zhanxiong, yes. That's what we know. The problem is the notation. Author uses $\mathcal I$ for the Fisher information.

Comment: For more discussion on the concept, check Section 4.3 of *Statistical Model* by A. C. Davison.  One thing is almost certain, the notation "$I(\theta)$" is reserved for (expected) Fisher information.  The observed information is usually denoted by $J(\theta)$ or $\hat{I}(\theta)$.

Comment: @ThePointer What your textbook put is $J(\theta)$ with one observation $x$ at hand, which in my opinion, is not "Fisher information".  Although in this case, $J(\hat{\theta}) = I(\hat{\theta})$, in general, this is not the case (suppose you observed $x_1$ and $x_2$).

Comment: @Zhanxiong That is what we are acquainted with. To be frank, I haven't studied Yudi Pawitan's text. But the author uses $I$ for the observed Fisher information and $\mathcal I$ for Fisher Information.

Comment: @User1865345 It seems not only about the subtle notation difference.  I am pointing out that calling "$\frac{x}{\theta^2} + \frac{n - x}{(1 - \theta)^2}$ "Fisher information" (as OP quoted) is very unconventional, if not wrong.  If the author clearly called $\frac{x}{\theta^2} + \frac{n - x}{(1 - \theta)^2}$ as "observed Fisher information" or "observed information", then I am fine.

Comment: I agree with you @Zhanxiong. Seeing initially made me nervous. I think your comment stating $J(\hat{\theta}) = I(\hat{\theta})$ is not the general case is useful for OP. May I urge you to add this in your post?

Comment: @User1865345 After some calculation, for binomial case, $I(\hat{\theta}) = J(\hat{\theta})$ is indeed true for all numbers of observations (I apologize for previous pre-matured comment).  However, this doesn't change my general view on this concept (even he used $\mathcal{I}$ for Fisher information and $I$ for observed information, the problem as stated in my previous comment still stands).

Comment: Very well @Zhanxiong. I again urge you to add these valuable pieces in your answer.

Comment: @User1865345 Done per your urge!

Comment: Thanks @Zhanxiong. Even for general purpose, this post would be helpful way beyond OP's requirements. +1.