# What am I doing wrong when finding the Fisher information of a binomial distribution with $n=2$?

Tags: binomial-distribution, fisher-information

I am trying to find the Fisher information of a binomial distribution where $n=2$ and $p=\theta$. I have the log-likelihood function as $$n\ln2 + \sum^{n}_{i=1}x_i\ln \theta + (2n-\sum^{n}_{i=1}x_i)(ln(1-\theta))-\sum^{n}_{i=1}(\ln x_i!+\ln((2-x_i)!))$$I have the second partial derivative of the log-likelihood function as $$\frac{-\sum^{n}_{i=1}x_i}{\theta^2}-\frac{2n-\sum^{n}_{i=1}x_i}{(1-\theta)^2}$$

When I go to take the negative expectation of this, I get $$\frac{n}{\theta}+\frac{2n-n\theta}{(1-\theta)^2}$$ which simplifies to $\frac{n}{\theta(1-\theta)^2}$. I know that the Fisher information is supposed to be $\frac{n}{\theta(1-\theta)}$, but I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong that gets rid of the square. I think it has to do with the $2n$ somewhere along the line, but I cannot figure out where. Does my log-likelihood function look right? What about the negative expectation?

Comment: 1. You can drop both of the terms that don't involve $\theta$ since they will disappear when you take the first derivative anyway.  2. Why does your third term in the first equation have $2n$?  If $n=2$, then that should just be $2$.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/602524/20519

Comment: Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4884056/321264.

Comment: It's not clear from your question (or your notation) what the exact setup is. Do you have a single observation $X \sim \mathrm{Bin}(n,\theta)$ where $n=1$ or a random sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n \sim \mathrm{Bin}(2, \theta)$?

Answer (score 0):

So for a binomial distribution with $n$ trials $x_1,...,x_n$ and probability $\theta$ we have the likelihood

$$L(X|\theta)=\binom{n}{\sum x_i}\theta^{\sum x_i}(1-\theta)^{(n-\sum x_i)}$$

log-likelihood:

$$l=\log\binom{n}{\sum x_i}+\sum x_i\log\theta+(n-\sum x_i)\log(1-\theta)$$

First derivative:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}l=\frac{\sum x_i}{\theta}-\frac{n-\sum x_i}{1-\theta}$$

Second derivative:

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}l=-\frac{\sum x_i}{\theta^2}-\frac{n-\sum x_i}{(1-\theta)^2}=\frac{-(1-\theta)^2\sum x_i-\theta^2(n-\sum x_i)}{\theta^2(1-\theta)^2}=\frac{-\sum x_i+2\theta\sum x_i-\theta^2\sum x_i-\theta^2n+\theta^2\sum x_i}{\theta^2(1-\theta)^2}=\frac{-(1-2\theta)\sum x_i-\theta^2n}{\theta^2(1-\theta)^2}$$

Information:

$$I(\theta)=-E\left[ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}l \right]=-E\left[\frac{-(1-2\theta)\sum x_i-\theta^2n}{\theta^2(1-\theta)^2}\right]=\frac{(1-2\theta)E\left[\sum x_i\right]+\theta^2n}{\theta^2(1-\theta)^2}=\frac{(1-2\theta)\theta n+\theta^2n}{\theta^2(1-\theta)^2}=\frac{\theta n-2\theta^2n+\theta^2n}{\theta^2(1-\theta)^2}=\frac{\theta n(1-\theta)}{\theta^2(1-\theta)^2}=\frac{n}{\theta(1-\theta)}.\blacksquare$$

Comment: The likelihood in the question has terms of the form $x_i!$ and $(2-x_i)!$, which seems to suggest that the sample is from a $\mathrm{Bin}(2,\theta)$, not a $\mathrm{Bernoulli}(\theta)$ (as in your answer), but it's not entirely clear.

Comment: As I understand the question, these terms come from the binomial coefficient and correspond to the assumption $n=2$

Comment: Then what does $n$ represent in the upper limit of the sum?

Comment: You sum over the different $x_i$ values. It seems as if the OP has some serious notation issues there (indexing using $x$ for some reason), fixed it now. Eagerly expecting their response regarding you setup comment, which might be crucial here. It is indeed very unclear.